# How to get the average execution time of a command in MacOS

Tags: macos, time

In MacOS, how can I get the average execution time (in milliseconds) of a command from executing it, say, 10 times? I've seen many questions addressing this for Linux systems, but I've not found a simple single-function solution for MacOS that can be added to the `.bashrc`/`.zshrc` and used for a flexible amount/format of commands.

Answer (score 0):

After trying several options, I've finally found the solution:

- I wanted the time in milliseconds, and I had problems doing this in MacOS. There were many places that used `date +%s%N`, but `%N` does not work in the `date` implementation in MacOS. To fix this, I had to install coreutils:

  ```
  brew rm coreutils && brew install coreutils
  ```
- Then, I created this bash function which you can add to your `.bashrc`/`.zshrc`:

  ```
  perf() {
    local times=10
    local total_duration=0
    local command=$@
    for _ in `seq $times`; {
      local start=$(/usr/local/opt/coreutils/libexec/gnubin/date +%s%3N)
      $@
      local time_taken=$(($(/usr/local/opt/coreutils/libexec/gnubin/date +%s%3N)-${start}))
      total_duration=$((${total_duration} + ${time_taken}))
    }
    echo "Total duration: ${total_duration} ms"
    echo "Average duration: ${$((${total_duration} / ${times}))} ms"
  }
  ```
- Then, simply run your command as:

  ```
  perf <command>
  ```